# AutoIt detect key press from Application

Tags: input, autoit

I am looking at a way of detecting Input from the Application Caffeine.  By default the Caffeine Application simulates user input by using the F15 key.  How would I Detect this within a AUtoItV3 script ?

I have the following (i understand how it works, but it doesn't get the input from Caffeine)

```
   HotKeySet("+{F3}", "_F15") ; shift F3

Func _F15()
    MsgBox(262144, Default, "F15", 0)
EndFunc   ;==>_F14
```

Thanks,

Comment: …If you want to detect the `F15` key, why aren't you doing `HotKeySet("{F15}", "_F15")`?

Comment: so your code and your question does not match....if you want to see if a key was pressed check out https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_IsPressed.htm

Comment: Shift + F3 is the only way that I can mimic F15 on my standard Keyboard.